# What is the time unit of Wiener process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

For a Wiener process, we know that the mean is $0$ and the variance is $\delta t$. But I am not sure how to interpret $\delta t$. For starter, what is the unit of the time? If the Wiener process is applied to model a stock's daily return, does it follow that the unit of $\delta t$ is one day?

Comment: Start with an i.i.d. Gaussian process $W_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, and consider the function with random values $w_1(n+t) = W_n$ whenever $0 \le t < 1$. Then, stretch it : $w_N(t) = \frac{w_1(N t)}{\sqrt{N}}$ and consider the limit case $N \to \infty$. You can see that $\lim_{N \to \infty} w_N(t)$ is not well-defined, but $B(t) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\int_0^t w_N(t) dt$ is : it is the Wiener process,  and the sequence of finite difference $X_a(n) = B(a(n+1))-B(a n)$ is Gaussian i.i.d. with variance $a \sigma^2$